# Prolog - Need help optimizing my code

Tags: database, search, optimization, prolog, find

I just started learning Prolog and I am doing a school task. I have written the program and it has "passed" all the test cases that have been thrown at it but the program "tester" still fails me because the time limit was exceeded. In other words my program is too slow.

Just for context: In this task I am given a "database" of people which also specifies which of these people are "friends" with each other AKA know each other. Among these people there are "spiders" and "conspirators". They have the following 
characteristics:

- The spider in the network is "friends" with all the conspirators (but maybe also with people who aren't)
- None of the conspirators is friends with any other conspirator.
- All the other people who are neither a conspirator or a spider do not know any conspirators.

My task is to identify the spiders in the web-like network (database).

My code:

```
% Test with all persons.
spider(X):-
  % Takes the next person from the example
  person(X),
  findSpider(X).

findSpider(X):-
  % Finds this persons Friends
  allFriends(X,Friends),
  % Returns list with friends that don't know each other AKA Possible Conspirators.
  getPConspirators(Friends, [], PossibleConspirators),
  % Checks if all persons are friends with some(any) conspirator. If True then X is a spider.
  isDefiniteSpider(PossibleConspirators),
  !.


allFriends(X, Friends):-
  % Bagof fails if no Friends exist.
  bagof(Friend, friend(X,Friend), Friends).

% Checks if friendship goes both ways.
friend(A,B) :- knows(A,B) ; knows(B,A).


% Check if P knows anyone in the list. True or false.
hasFriend(P, Lst):-
  not(hasFriendHelp(P, Lst)).

% Return true if P doesn't know anybody in the list.
hasFriendHelp(_, []).

hasFriendHelp(P, [H|T]):-
  not(friend(P, H)),
  hasFriendHelp(P, T).


% Takes the spiders friends and returns a list with persons who don't know each other.
getPConspirators([], Res, Res).

getPConspirators([H|T], Conspirators, Res):-
  not(hasFriend(H, Conspirators)), % H has no friend among the conspirators.
  getPConspirators(T, [H|Conspirators], Res). % Move on.

getPConspirators([_|T], Conspirators, Res) :-
  getPConspirators(T, Conspirators, Res).


% Checks if all persons know anybody in the list PossibleConspirators.
% If this is the case return True, otherwise False.
isDefiniteSpider(PossibleConspirators):-
  forall(person(Y),
  (member(Y,PossibleConspirators);hasFriend(Y,PossibleConspirators))).
```

Example of what the given data looks like:

```
person(0).
person(1).
person(2).
person(3).
person(4).
person(5).
person(6).
person(7).
person(8).
person(9).
person(10).
person(11).
person(12).
person(13).
person(14).
person(15).
person(16).
person(17).
person(18).
person(19).
person(20).
person(21).
person(22).
person(23).
person(24).
knows(0,1).
knows(0,2).
knows(0,3).
knows(0,4).
knows(0,5).
knows(0,6).
knows(0,7).
knows(0,8).
knows(0,9).
knows(1,2).
knows(1,3).
knows(1,4).
knows(1,5).
knows(1,6).
knows(1,7).
knows(1,8).
knows(1,9).
knows(1,10).
knows(2,3).
knows(2,4).
knows(2,5).
knows(2,6).
knows(2,7).
knows(2,8).
knows(2,9).
knows(2,10).
knows(2,11).
knows(3,4).
knows(3,5).
knows(3,6).
knows(3,7).
knows(3,8).
knows(3,9).
knows(3,10).
knows(3,11).
knows(3,12).
knows(4,5).
knows(4,6).
knows(4,7).
knows(4,8).
knows(4,9).
knows(4,10).
knows(4,11).
knows(4,12).
knows(4,13).
knows(5,6).
knows(5,7).
knows(5,8).
knows(5,9).
knows(5,10).
knows(5,11).
knows(5,12).
knows(5,13).
knows(5,14).
knows(6,7).
knows(6,8).
knows(6,9).
knows(6,10).
knows(6,11).
knows(6,12).
knows(6,13).
knows(6,14).
knows(6,15).
knows(7,8).
knows(7,9).
knows(7,10).
knows(7,11).
knows(7,12).
knows(7,13).
knows(7,14).
knows(7,15).
knows(7,16).
knows(8,9).
knows(8,10).
knows(8,11).
knows(8,12).
knows(8,13).
knows(8,14).
knows(8,15).
knows(8,16).
knows(8,17).
knows(9,10).
knows(9,11).
knows(9,12).
knows(9,13).
knows(9,14).
knows(9,15).
knows(9,16).
knows(9,17).
knows(9,18).
knows(10,11).
knows(10,12).
knows(10,13).
knows(10,14).
knows(10,15).
knows(10,16).
knows(10,17).
knows(10,18).
knows(10,19).
knows(11,12).
knows(11,13).
knows(11,14).
knows(11,15).
knows(11,16).
knows(11,17).
knows(11,18).
knows(11,19).
knows(11,20).
knows(12,13).
knows(12,14).
knows(12,15).
knows(12,16).
knows(12,17).
knows(12,18).
knows(12,19).
knows(12,20).
knows(12,21).
knows(13,14).
knows(13,15).
knows(13,16).
knows(13,17).
knows(13,18).
knows(13,19).
knows(13,20).
knows(13,21).
knows(13,22).
knows(14,15).
knows(14,16).
knows(14,17).
knows(14,18).
knows(14,19).
knows(14,20).
knows(14,21).
knows(14,22).
knows(14,23).
knows(15,16).
knows(15,17).
knows(15,18).
knows(15,19).
knows(15,20).
knows(15,21).
knows(15,22).
knows(15,23).
knows(15,24).
knows(16,17).
knows(16,18).
knows(16,19).
knows(16,20).
knows(16,21).
knows(16,22).
knows(16,23).
knows(16,24).
knows(16,0).
knows(17,18).
knows(17,19).
knows(17,20).
knows(17,21).
knows(17,22).
knows(17,23).
knows(17,24).
knows(17,0).
knows(17,1).
knows(18,19).
knows(18,20).
knows(18,21).
knows(18,22).
knows(18,23).
knows(18,24).
knows(18,0).
knows(18,1).
knows(18,2).
knows(19,20).
knows(19,21).
knows(19,22).
knows(19,23).
knows(19,24).
knows(19,0).
knows(19,1).
knows(19,2).
knows(19,3).
knows(20,21).
knows(20,22).
knows(20,23).
knows(20,24).
knows(20,0).
knows(20,1).
knows(20,2).
knows(20,3).
knows(20,4).
knows(21,22).
knows(21,23).
knows(21,24).
knows(21,0).
knows(21,1).
knows(21,2).
knows(21,3).
knows(21,4).
knows(21,5).
knows(22,23).
knows(22,24).
knows(22,0).
knows(22,1).
knows(22,2).
knows(22,3).
knows(22,4).
knows(22,5).
knows(22,6).
knows(23,24).
knows(23,0).
knows(23,1).
knows(23,2).
knows(23,3).
knows(23,4).
knows(23,5).
knows(23,6).
knows(23,7).
knows(24,0).
knows(24,1).
knows(24,2).
knows(24,3).
knows(24,4).
knows(24,5).
knows(24,6).
knows(24,7).
knows(24,8).
```

I have no idea which one of my functions are the "slow one". Maybe there are multiple? How do I speed it up? Any tips? Much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps it is worth explaining your approach. This is both beneficial for us, and yourself: sometimes I find optimizations when explaining an algorithm/code to somebody else (or even myself).

Comment: I tested your program, it answers that every person is a spider... what's up ?

Comment: @CapelliC in that particular test data every person is a spider so that is correct.

Comment: If you do `trace. spider(X).`, Prolog will show you what it's spending its time doing, and you might get a sense of the nature of the problem. This algorithm is very inefficient because you're just having Prolog exhaustively try everything.